# Error in using Spinner Class

Tags: android, spinner

```
package com.example.acer.spinner;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.internal.widget.AdapterViewCompat;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;


public  class MainActivity extends Activity implements AdapterViewCompat.OnItemSelectedListener        {

Spinner s,d;
String source[]={"kc","tc"};
String destination[]={"kc","tc"};
TextView t;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    s=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    d=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    t=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
    ArrayAdapter<String> so = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,source);
    s.setAdapter(so);
    ArrayAdapter<String> de = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,destination);
    d.setAdapter(de);

    s.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            position=s.getSelectedItemPosition();
            t.setText("" +position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
}
}
```

This program is not executable because it is being said that the class MainActivity has to be made abstract or to implement OnNothingSelected method? Why is it so?
However, on making the class abstract, the App is not running.
What changes should be made?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't implement the methods of the abstract class "AdapterViewCompat"

```
@Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterViewCompat<?> adapterViewCompat, View view, int i, long l) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterViewCompat<?> adapterViewCompat) {

    }
```

Comment: Thanks..It worked. But haven't those methods been already used in the listener?

Comment: You should remove  "implements AdapterViewCompat.OnItemSelectedListener " and the implements methods.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to solve:

```
    package com.example.acer.spinner;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.internal.widget.AdapterViewCompat;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;


public  class MainActivity extends Activity    {

Spinner s,d;
String source[]={"kc","tc"};
String destination[]={"kc","tc"};
TextView t;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    s=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    d=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    t=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
    ArrayAdapter<String> so = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,source);
    s.setAdapter(so);
    ArrayAdapter<String> de = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,destination);
    d.setAdapter(de);

    s.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            position=s.getSelectedItemPosition();
            t.setText("" +position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
}
}
```

And the second:

```
    package com.example.acer.spinner;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.internal.widget.AdapterViewCompat;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.Spinner;
    import android.widget.TextView;


    public  class MainActivity extends Activity implements AdapterViewCompat.OnItemSelectedListener        {

    Spinner s,d;
    String source[]={"kc","tc"};
    String destination[]={"kc","tc"};
    TextView t;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        s=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        d=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        t=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
        ArrayAdapter<String> so = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,source);
        s.setAdapter(so);
        ArrayAdapter<String> de = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,destination);
        d.setAdapter(de);

        s.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    }
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterViewCompat<?> adapterViewCompat, View view, int i, long l) {
        if(view.getId()==R.id.spinner1){
                position=s.getSelectedItemPosition();
                t.setText("" +position);

}

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterViewCompat<?> adapterViewCompat) {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove your AdapterViewCompat.OnItemSelectedListener implementation from your MainActivity class.
Before:

```
public  class MainActivity extends Activity implements AdapterViewCompat.OnItemSelectedListener
```

After:

```
public  class MainActivity extends Activity
```